# How to set the background color for an entire column(indication for Readonly column) in datagridview in c#.net

Tags: datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a datagridview in which I want to set `readonly` to `true` for two columns. I want to change the color for those columns. Whenever I leave from the cell I'm able to make only the first cell and current cell change color. Remaining cells are not working. Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly)
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].ReadOnly)
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Black;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DataGridViewColumn dgv7col = dgv7.Columns[i];
    DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
    dgv7col.CellTemplate = cell;
```

you have to define the column not the cell Ronny

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
        if (col.ReadOnly) 
            col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

if (grdView.Columns["Columnname"].ReadOnly)
                        grdView.Columns["Columnname"].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Lavender;